# Importing data into Excel using XML and Excel Templates

Tags: c#, xml, excel, csv, import

I am generating CSV data from a C# application. This can be imported into Excel easily but I need formatting applied to the file.

One option is interop but the machine running this application will not have Office products installed so that is out.

I've been told that XML can work with Excel templates and am looking for a starter example on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have generated excel spread sheets using the excel 2003 xml format several times but you will have to consider the following features that cannot be supported using this format:

> This XML Spreadsheet 2003 file format (.xml) does not retain the following features:
>
> - Auditing tracer arrows
> - Chart and other graphic objects
> - Chart sheets, macro sheets, dialog sheets
> - Custom views
> - Data consolidation references
> - Drawing object layers
> - Outlining and grouping features
> - Password-protected worksheet data
> - Scenarios
> - User-defined function categories
> - VBA projects

If that is acceptable you can use as someone suggest an open source library that allows you to generate the spreadsheet in code or as I have done you can generate the xml using either an xml transform or a using the [spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/) template engine. Both have worked for me in the past but using the spark view engine was probably the nicest.

The best way to achieve either of these is to create a template the way you want it to look and save it as a Excel 2003 Xml format and look at the raw xml. This should make it easy for you to generate your output. You can also download the xml definition for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using a simple XML macro-enabled template to read the XML files.

Comment: @RaheelKhan, it is nice that you provide feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use excellent OpenXML wrapper [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to generate xlsx files with formatting. Or if you want, you can use pure [OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124). OpenXML installation is required for ClosedXML to work.